# "in car" which doesn't have any article

Tags: articles, headlinese

[Golden Retriever puppy dozes off in car after exhausting day out](https://www.msn.com/en-us/video/animals/golden-retriever-puppy-dozes-off-in-car-after-exhausting-day-out/vi-BBXFbM4)

I know "in car" should be "in a car" or "in the car" in the above sentence. It's the title of a public media.

Is it correct to use "in car" without any article? If so, does it have any special meaning? I can't find any usage like that in my English dictionary and Google search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newspaper headlines often use this telegraphic and strictly speaking ungrammatical convention.

From back in the days of typesetting with molten lead, they want to squeeze in as many content words as possible into a small space.

Comment: See [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).